# How can I do correlation of a dataframe without returning Value Error?

Tags: python, dataframe, linear-regression, correlation

Just started my ML recently and from my tutorials I see them finding correlation of data using `data.corr()`. Doing it the same way gives a **ValueError**.

I tried converting the whole data into numerics by performing:

```
data.select_dtype(include=('number'))
```

and

```
pd.get_dummies(data.string_column).astype(int)
```

On fitting the training data into the model, I get errors of not being able to convert string to float.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.